# How to identify (remove) the source of popup messagebox at Windows XP boot?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot, troubleshooting, debug

A computer of one of my users during the boot of its Windows XP SP3 is insistingly showing a messagebox with different illegible symbols in body and title é requiring  to press OK

If to leave this messagebox without pressing OK, then the title and body with illegible content are changing every half minute.

Eventvwr doesn't show anything helpful

The system is checked and treated by multiple antivirusesm registry cleaners, registry defragmenting utilities, system and hardware checking applications, etc.

I've tried all I could find by search on internet. For example, [How to Suppress Error Messages During Boot Process](http://www.instant-registry-fixes.org/how-to-suppress-error-messages-during-boot-process/). Nothing succeded so far

This also happens if to boot

- from DVD
- in safe mode (though in safe mode the content is not auto-changing periodically)
- to disable any processes on startup!

It is after loading drivers but before Welcome screen.

Tweaking BIOS settings did not help.

In **boot.ini** I created 2 entries for loading Windows XP with /bootlog switcher and another without. So, I could get boot log on complete loading and until the messagebox (by hard restart on messagebox and choosing the next booting without bootlog in order to avoid its overwriting).

Though the last record on hard restart is always different one.

What are the possible ways to identify the source of a popup (or get rid of it without finding the cause)

Comment: Screenshot would be helpful. And by God, please don't visit any 'registry fix' sites.

Comment: If it's happening even when you boot for DVD it may be something in the computer's BIOS settings. Usually you can hit a special key like Delete or F2 to enter the systems's BIOS settings utility.

Comment: I do not know how to make screenshot in the middle of a boot. I do not have a photocamera. Besides the text and title are changing all the time, even at the same boot, if to leave the messagebox without pressing OK button

Comment: When you say, this happens when booting from DVD, what DVD are you booting into? At what specific point in the boot process does this happen? Before the Windows logo? After?

Comment: What exactly does `Yweeking` mean?

Comment: Ramhound, "Yweeking" is a honey trap for eggheads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), click on the aim button in the tool bar and drag it over the message box.

This will highlight the process to which the message box belongs.